# How to get around Marshal.Copy (32bit) length limit?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interop

I'm trying to move data back/forth between managed (C#) and unmanaged (C++ Win32) code.  I can use `Marshal.Copy` and it works just fine until the datasets get bigger > 2GB as `Marshal.Copy` has a signed 32 bit int (2GB) limit for length.

Any idea how to get around this?  Currently I use `AllocHGlobal(IntPtr)` on the managed side and `.ToPointer()` on the unmanaged side.  If I can't use `Marshal.Copy` to move large data (> 2GB) back/forth what can I use?

Comment: How about just calling it multiple times with an offset?

Comment: check this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652911/how-to-alloc-more-than-maxinteger-bytes-of-memory-in-c-sharp

Comment: So I would have to divide up my memory into 2GB chunks, call AllocHGlobal several times to produce several different chunks, then do Marshal.Copy a few times?   Any way to keep this together in one big chunk of memory (>2GB)?    I have Windows 7 64bit with 40GB of RAM.  I wouldn't be trying this on a 32 bit machine.

Comment: Sorry, that's my fault, according Marshal.Copy reference this will not work:  startIndex and length is 32bit.

Comment: Why are you copying in the first place? Just fix the C# array in memory, and pass the pointer to it to the unmanaged code. But I think .net doesn't support arrays >2GB in the first place.

Comment: Why not use a memory-mapped file instead of doing everything in actual physical RAM?

Comment: C#.NET lets me create byte[] arrays >2GB.  the question is how to transfer them to the other side (Win32 world).

Comment: MemoryMappedFile is a .net class

Comment: I can allocate over 2GB of memory with AllocHGlobal.  I just can't copy data into the allocated memory.  I suppose what I'm looking for is some sort of trick with Marshal.StructureToPtr and PtrToStructure.  However these commands don't seem to like the C# byte[] object.  They complain about it not being blitable.

Comment: You cannot directly access that memory on the C++ side either.  A pretty fundamental limitation in x64 cores, indexed offset addressing has a 32-bit signed offset with no option for 64-bit offsets without using another register.  You'll have to come up with a smarter data structure, that should not be difficult.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to copy gigabytes of data around, when you can just access the .net array from native code.

Comment: I would think that if you need to copy that much data between contexts (managed and unmanaged) then you have a design flaw.  If you would let us know what the purpose of copying the data is maybe we can provide an alternative approach.  And to repeat those who came before me the MemoryMappedFile will allow you to access the same data from difference contexts or even processes.

Comment: Memory Mapped files are available under win32. See more details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction was: why are your copying 2GB+ of data?

Perhaps your application constraints won't allow it, but it seems to me that if your data set is that larger than what is allowed by the framework you should not be looking for trick to get around the framework. How about another method of access altogether?

There are numerous ways around this problem. For starters you could wrap the memory in a stream and pull the data into the unmanaged code. You could also create your own interface to bring the data in piece meal. Memory mapped files come to mind as well.

Without knowing the specific contstraints of the application, maybe you cannot change the unmanaged code, I would suggest finding another method rather than working around the framework.