# What's the correct way to marshal a const float**?

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to read an array that's created by pinvoking a dll function from C#. When I print out the array's contents it's actually full of junk.

I suspect this is happening because I am incorrectly marshalling a `const float**` to an `out IntPtr`. How do you properly marshal a `const float**`?

**DLL C++ Interface**

```
int Foo(void *objPtr, uint64_t *resultLen, const float **result);
```

**DLL Import Statement**

```
[DllImport("foo.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int Foo(IntPtr objPtr, out ulong resultLen, out IntPtr result);
```

**Calling Code**

```
IntPtr objPtr = getObj();
IntPtr result;
ulong resultLen;
int output = Foo(objPtr, out resultLen, out result);
```

Comment: Shown example c++ code that calls the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is no way to tell the marshaler the size of the array ahead of time you will have to copy the array manually. So `out IntPtr` is correct.

Note you *will* have a problem with very large arrays. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx and [How to get around Marshal.Copy (32bit) length limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103958/how-to-get-around-marshal-copy-32bit-length-limit) . This snippet will use `int` as the resulting array length. You will need to figure out what to do in your particular case.

Also note your DLL must be responsible for releasing the memory it allocates. See [Release unmanaged memory from managed C# with pointer of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273961/release-unmanaged-memory-from-managed-c-sharp-with-pointer-of-it) .

```
IntPtr objPtr = getObj();
IntPtr result;
int resultLen;

// call your external function
int output = Foo(objPtr, out resultLen, out result); 

// create an array to hold the output data
float[] array = new float[resultLen];

// copy the data
Marshal.Copy(result, array, 0, resultLen);

// since the memory was allocated by the DLL only it knows how to free it
// so call the free function exported by the DLL
FreeBufferAfterFoo(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since you're saying `out IntPtr` is correct and since I've got the equivalent of your extra code in my personal code, it seems the reason for having junk in my array must be unrelated to how I marshalled `const float**`. I upvoted your answer since it was very informative although my problem isn't solved yet. If there isn't any other answer for a while that might have a different suggestion, I'll edit the question to just be about marshalling `const float**` and I'll accept your answer. Thanks again :)